# What is the best way to retrieve Azure Monitor events using Java?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-eventhub, azure-monitoring

I am trying to write some Java code that analyses data from Azure Monitor sources, such as subscription events, services metrics, etc.
I'd like to do two things :
1. Persist the data to ElasticSearch .
2. Do some simple analysis (simple example : count number of specific events)

The only way i found to export this data is through Azure Event-Hub service, which seems to be a lot more robust than what i need. Is there a simpler way? If i'm able to retrieve the events/messages in my Java code, than i can do the analysis and persistance on my own, but from the guides iv'e read it sounds like i need to use 3-4 additional services to do the simple Azure Monitor -> Java code transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the metrics using REST API however you may not get the data in real time:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricdefinitions/list

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list

I'm not sure why you want to move the data to another place since you can get the information you need using Kusto / Power BI for it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/get-started-queries

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/powerbi

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/powerbi-connector